# problem with showing .eps graph on output .pdf with xelatex?

Tags: xetex, eps

I am new to xelatex and use TeXstudio 2.9.4 with MiKTeX 2.9  !

I've recently upgraded from pdflatex to xelatex, due to the easy handling of new fonts in xelatex.

But the new problem I am facing is with .eps files. I have a number of graphs in .eps format, which xelatex is not showing in output .pdf file.  Besides that, code is compiled successfully but without any graphs.

I did google out the issue but didn't get successful. One way I found, is to use the .pdf image of the .eps image which epstopdf had generated earlier. However, it is cumbersome if the graphs are large in number and get changed from time to time.

Any remedy to cope the issue will be very helpful to me. I am on TeXstudio 2.9.4 and using txs:///xelatex as my default compiler.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,final,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\pagebreak
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\hyphenation{}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimal Example}
\maketitle

 \begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
   \captionsetup{justification=centering}
  \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{fig.eps}
  \caption{data-set $ z_3. $}
  \label{F1}
  \end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

The following warnings are displayed:

** WARNING ** No image converter available for converting file "C:/Users/Hawk/Desktop/fig.eps" to PDF format. ** WARNING ** >> Please check if you have 'D' option in config file. ** WARNING ** pdf: image inclusion failed for "fig.eps". ** WARNING ** Failed to read image file: fig.eps ** WARNING ** Interpreting special command PSfile (ps:) failed. ** WARNING ** >> at page="26" position="(162, 488.22)" (in PDF) ** WARNING ** >> xxx "PSfile="fig.eps" urx=448.3

These are the settings I made for xelatex to work in TeXstudio:
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about your document. Preferably providing a minimal example showing the smallest compilable document you can provide where including an `.eps` is a problem. Are you sure you are not under, say, draft mode?

Comment: @daleif minimal example is added in question.

Comment: Still no problem when I replace `fig.eps` with one I already have. Exactly which system are you on? Why exactly are you using `xelatex`,  does IEEE allow `xelatex`?

Comment: I need xelatex to incorporate some new font in my text, which is not possible in pdflatex. 
I am on TeXstudio 2.9.4, Windows 7 professional, 32 bit centrinoduo processor.

Comment: Texstudio is not relevant. Which LaTeX dist? (I'm using TeX Live 2014 frozen) And again, does IEEE allow you to use special fonts? That dont may not be available in IEEEs production setup, thus your work might be in vain. Do you get any errors or warnings.

Comment: MiKTeX 2.9 !! I am using just one customized glyph (character) to differentiate it from other symbols . Which are allowed in IEEE. ** WARNING ** No image converter available for converting file "C:/Users/Hawk/Desktop/fig.eps" to PDF format. ** WARNING ** >> Please check if you have 'D' option in config file.  ** WARNING ** pdf: image inclusion failed for "fig.eps". ** WARNING ** Failed to read image file: fig.eps ** WARNING ** Interpreting special command PSfile (ps:) failed. ** WARNING ** >> at page="26" position="(162, 488.22)" (in PDF) ** WARNING ** >> xxx "PSfile="fig.eps" urx=448.3

Comment: You might want to add that warning to the original question and hope for someone with more knowledge about xelatex to come along. Is that specific `fig.eps` available anywhere? Have you tried manually converting it to PDF via the commandline? (`epstopdf fig.eps`). It might be the EPS that has errors. Many of the converters are very specific.

Comment: The same fig.eps works fine with pdflatex. Thanks for your consistent advice and effort to pull me out from trouble. I will put the required editing in my question sometime tomorrow, need to sleep now. Good night !

Comment: @daleif Finally got successful to run xelatex and lualatex (and pdflatex too), based on your comments. I did first uninstall both MiKTex and Texstudio, and then I install TeX Live and Texstudio. Done !